# Brower loads the same Image 2 times

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to preload Images and use it with css background-image, but I'm having troubles making the browser(only tested with Chrome at the moment) preload the Images.

I'm loading the Images with this code:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= options.imageCount; i++){
    let img = new Image()
    var src = options.imagePath + i + "." + quality + "." + options.imageFormat

    img.onload = () => {
        completeCount += 1

        if(completeCount == options.imageCount){
            callback(true)
        }
    }

    img.src = src
}
```

If I try to append the Images object into a container it works fine.

`DOMImgContainer.appendChild(img);`

But if I try to use the Image with the css background-image property

`DOMZoom.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";`

the browser loads the image another time, instead of using the already preload.

[Network in DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWaMa.png)

In the image above the first item is the image loaded with the preload code, the second one is the same image loaded again once a clicked on a button and added the image in the background-image property of a container. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm kind of stumped why you're doing it this way instead of just setting the background image and shifting it as needed. Or using sprites. Or both.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. What is `imgData`?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The images are very large, so I want to make sure they're preloaded before rendering them in background-image

Comment: Yes, that's why one usually preloads them in the background-url with a no-repeat and a huge offset so they don't show, and then once they've loaded (or whatever other trigger) remove the offset.

Comment: @GiancarlloRojas Is there a reason why you start your for loop var at 1 instead of 0? Common practice would be to start at 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out that the problem was not related to the code, I was doing a full working snippet for this post and, well, It was working just fine on the snippet, so I went deeper and found that the culprit was actually http-server(NodeJS simple http server), the dev server I was using.

For some reason when my code ran on the http-server the browser could not preload the Images.

Comment: Maybe http-server passes along a no-cache flag making any manual preloading worthless as your browser will just decide to load them again.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have got the path wrong, hover your mouse over both of the image file names in the network tab and make sure that the full path matches.

Either that or your server is setting a no cache header but I am not sure if that would cause multiple loads of the same image on a single page or not.